# Is there any way to send a call message, requesting a transaction?

Tags: transactions, message

**Example:** The human owner of ERC20 wallet (X) owes the human owner of ERC20 wallet (Y) an amount of (T) ERC20.

Is there any function that the owner of Wallet (Y) can send a request message to the owner of Wallet (X) requesting the owed amount?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE! There is no method to "request" a payment from someone, mostly because the change would be done in that contract, and there is no way of "notifying" the involved party, especially if Y is a normal account address.

The current flows for ERC20 are:

- approval by X, then transferFrom(X) by Y
- transfer to Y by X

For ERC-677:

- When X is a contract, then you could rely on the "transferAndCall" method that notifies our receiver of a transfer.

But the **reverse** has not been proposed in a widely adopted standard as of yet, mostly because of the "notification issue".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Hmm, I understand, maybe there could be a workaround solution within a partly closed peer to peer network for example a wallet app sending a message from (Y) to (X). - should work as long as (X) and (Y) use the same wallet app.